# Change phone emulator

Tags: netbeans, java-me

My project in Netbeans is currently using the `JavaMEPhone1` phone emulator. How can I change this phone emulator to another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You download and install emulators from the various company sites. Here's a link for Nokia:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/6e772b17-604b-4081-999c-31f1f0dc2dbb/S60_Platform_SDKs_for_Symbian_OS_for_Java.html

Then the new installed emulators will become an option to choose, from within NetBeans.

Last time I checked though, it was not possible on a Linux machine. Don't know what OS you're running. But if it's Windows, you should be fine.